'module' is not accessed Pylance
enter image description here
enter image description here
there are darkened modules with the same problem 'is not accessed Pylance'.
I have been searching for hours and tried some ways on youtube and other media but no result.
Anyone got any tips to fix these problems? I am a newbie so I will appreciate every suggestions

That is a warning message that you are importing some modules that are never used.  Why are you bothering to import a module that you don't use?

It's not an error. The IDE (whatever program you are using to write your code in) is letting you know that those imports are not used in your code, thus you can delete them to reduce the time it runs and memory required as now your program will not need to load many modules just to never use them. You can safely delete them or ignore this :)
